# My proxy service doesn't work

Tags: wsdl, wso2, wso2-esb

I created a proxy service mapped on an external service running on my localhost inside Tomcat.
When I call via SOAPUI the Proxy Service I get the error:

> The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is
>   /services/TestWebService and the WSA Action = . If this EPR was
>   previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.

Here the WSDL of the proxy generated from my original WSDL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://apache.org/hello_world_soap_http" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:x1="http://apache.org/hello_world_soap_http/types" name="HelloWorld" targetNamespace="http://apache.org/hello_world_soap_http">
    <types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://apache.org/hello_world_soap_http/types" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://apache.org/hello_world_soap_http/types">
            <simpleType name="MyStringType">
                <restriction base="string">
                    <maxLength value="30"/>
                </restriction>
            </simpleType>
            <element name="sayHi">
                <complexType/>
            </element>
            <element name="sayHiResponse">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element name="responseType" type="string"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <element name="greetMe">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element name="requestType" type="tns:MyStringType"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <element name="greetMeResponse">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element name="responseType" type="string"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <element name="greetMeOneWay">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element name="requestType" type="string"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <element name="pingMe">
                <complexType/>
            </element>
            <element name="pingMeResponse">
                <complexType/>
            </element>
            <element name="faultDetail">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element name="minor" type="short"/>
                        <element name="major" type="short"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
        </schema>
    </types>
    <message name="sayHiRequest">
        <part name="in" element="x1:sayHi"/>
    </message>
    <message name="pingMeResponse">
        <part name="out" element="x1:pingMeResponse"/>
    </message>
    <message name="greetMeRequest">
        <part name="in" element="x1:greetMe"/>
    </message>
    <message name="sayHiResponse">
        <part name="out" element="x1:sayHiResponse"/>
    </message>
    <message name="greetMeResponse">
        <part name="out" element="x1:greetMeResponse"/>
    </message>
    <message name="pingMeRequest">
        <part name="in" element="x1:pingMe"/>
    </message>
    <message name="greetMeOneWayRequest">
        <part name="in" element="x1:greetMeOneWay"/>
    </message>
    <message name="pingMeFault">
        <part name="faultDetail" element="x1:faultDetail"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="Greeter">
        <operation name="sayHi">
            <input name="sayHiRequest" message="tns:sayHiRequest"/>
            <output name="sayHiResponse" message="tns:sayHiResponse"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="greetMe">
            <input name="greetMeRequest" message="tns:greetMeRequest"/>
            <output name="greetMeResponse" message="tns:greetMeResponse"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="greetMeOneWay">
            <input name="greetMeOneWayRequest" message="tns:greetMeOneWayRequest"/>
        </operation>
        <operation name="pingMe">
            <input name="pingMeRequest" message="tns:pingMeRequest"/>
            <output name="pingMeResponse" message="tns:pingMeResponse"/>
            <fault name="pingMeFault" message="tns:pingMeFault"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="Greeter_SOAPBinding" type="tns:Greeter">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="sayHi">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
            <input name="sayHiRequest">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output name="sayHiResponse">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="greetMe">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
            <input name="greetMeRequest">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output name="greetMeResponse">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="greetMeOneWay">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
            <input name="greetMeOneWayRequest">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
        </operation>
        <operation name="pingMe">
            <soap:operation style="document"/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
            <fault name="pingMeFault">
                <soap:fault name="pingMeFault" use="literal"/>
            </fault>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="SOAPService">
        <port name="SoapPort" binding="tns:Greeter_SOAPBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://WIN-PC:8280/services/TestWebService"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

What is the problem ? the SOAPAction operation empty ? other ?

Comment: try to access your wsdl from browser or use TcpMon to find out what`s really happening...

Comment: The access to the wsdl via browser works fine , and in the logs the error is that the dispatcher is unable to define the EndPoint

Answer (score 0):

What is the port are you using? Your URL should be something like this.

```
http://localhost:8280/services/TestWebService
```

Comment: The url of the backend endpoint targeted by the proxy is well correct.
Indeed, if I use TryIt on this proxy service I am able to join the backend , so the url is well defined.
Don't you think the problem doesn't come from the fact that the SOAPAction associated to my operations are null in the wsdl I provided.

Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

Waht is the service endpoint you pointed from SOAPUI? It is something like;

```
http://localhost:8280/services/yourproxy
```

AND what is your request you used to invoke the API? If your proxy is associated with a service wsdl(`using <publishwsdl> option`) , your request should map with that.Else you can use the actual request which you use to invoke the actual backend servcie.

Comment: I dowloaded the ESB 4.5.1 version and is works fine, so there is a bug in the 4.6 ...

Comment: Please could you confirm it is well a bug in ESB 4.6 as it works fine in 4.5.1 ?